# How can I bulid a wrapper on my .ipa file to capture the launch event

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, launch

I want to capture the launch event of an existing app. I have the .ipa file. Is there any way I can build a framework (to wrap my .ipa or  bundle that with app) that listens the launch event of my app.
I basically want to capture the launch events of teh ios apps.